# difficulties getting a 3 table join to return expected results

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having some difficulty getting to the bottom of this sql query.

Tables:

```
--Tickets--         --Finance--          --Access--
id_tickets          id_finance           id_access
name_tickets        id_event             id_event
cat_tickets         id_tickets           id_tickets
                    sold_finance         scan_access
```

Finance and Access both contain a row for multiple of each ticket type as listed in tickets.
and I'm trying to get:

```
cat_tickets | total_sold | total_scan
-------------------------------------
single      | 3043       | 2571
season      | 481        | 292
comp        | 114        | 75
-------------------------------------
total       | 3638       | 2938
```

The closest I've been to the result I've used:

```
SELECT tickets.cat_tickets, COALESCE(SUM(finance.sold_finance), 0) AS total_sold, COALESCE(SUM(access.scan_access), 0) AS total_scan
FROM finance INNER JOIN tickets ON finance.id_tickets = tickets.id_tickets
INNER JOIN access ON access.id_tickets = tickets.id_tickets
WHERE access.id_event = 235 AND finance.id_event = access.id_event
GROUP BY tickets.cat_tickets
ORDER BY tickets.cat_tickets DESC
```

but that just returns:

```
cat_tickets | total_sold | total_scan
-------------------------------------
single      | 4945       | 4437
season      | 954        | 599
comp        | 342        | 375
-------------------------------------
total       | 6241       | 5411
```

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: it is not clear how your tables are related with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the relation between `access` and `finance` tables, you have to `join` them. Even if you `LEFT JOIN` the table the predicate `finance.id_event = access.id_event` will make it `INNER JOIN`. As a work around, use `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT 
  tickets.cat_tickets, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'f' THEN num ELSE 0 END) AS total_sold,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'a' THEN num ELSE 0 END) AS total_scan
FROM tickets 
LEFT JOIN
( 
  SELECT 'f' Type, id_tickets, sold_finance num
  FROM finance f
  WHERE id_event = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', id_tickets, scan_access
  FROM access 
  WHERE id_event = 1
) a ON a.id_tickets = tickets.id_tickets
GROUP BY tickets.cat_tickets;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/725de/1)

Comment: I tried it out (after adding the correct event id) but the result was also incorrect.  It was similar to the error I was getting though slightly different by a few figures

Comment: Excellent!  How did the 'work around' work?  Is there limitations to this approach?  What the hell is actually happening?

Comment: @AlanDoolan I get all the data from the two tables into one query which is the joined subquery, with a new column `Type` works as a flag, `f` for those coming from the finance table, and `a` for those coming from the access table. Then I used `LEFT JOIN` in the outer query to get all the tickets, regardless it has rows or not in the two other table, then there are three case: one if the ticket has no rows in the two tables, then the two sums will be 0 because the `Type` will be `NULL` therefore 0.

Comment: @AlanDoolan Second, if the ticket has rows only in finance then `Type` will be `f` then it will sum the values of `sold_finance`. Third, if the ticket has rows only in access then `Type` will be `a` then it will sum the values of `scan_access` only. And this is what the `CASE` expression does.

Comment: ...the explanation is more confusing than the answer.  Ok, well I guess I have a lot of learning to do with this sql malarky.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Although I am fully clear on what you want, just try this query if the result of this is what you are expecting.

```
SELECT tickets.cat_tickets, COALESCE(SUM(finance.sold_finance), 0) AS total_sold, COALESCE(SUM(access.scan_access), 0) AS total_scan
FROM finance LEFT JOIN tickets ON finance.id_tickets = tickets.id_tickets
LEFT JOIN access ON access.id_tickets = tickets.id_tickets
WHERE access.id_event = 235
GROUP BY tickets.cat_tickets
ORDER BY tickets.cat_tickets DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: *This query is not tested due to incomplete data on the question.*

```
SELECT  z.Cat_tickets,
        COALESCE(x.total_sold,0) total_sold,
        COALESCE(y.total_scan,0) total_scan
FROM    tickets z
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.id_tickets,
                    a.cat_tickets, 
                    SUM(b.sold_finance) total_sold
            FROM    tickets a
                    INNER JOIN finance b
                        ON a.id_tickets = b.id_tickets
            WHERE   id_event = 235
            GROUP   BY a.id_tickets, a.cat_tickets
        ) x ON z.id_tickets = x.id_tickets
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  aa.id_tickets,
                    aa.cat_tickets, 
                    SUM(bb.scan_access) total_scan
            FROM    tickets aa
                    INNER JOIN Access bb
                        ON aa.id_tickets = bb.id_tickets
            WHERE   id_event = 235
            GROUP   BY aa.id_tickets, aa.cat_tickets
        ) y ON z.id_tickets = y.id_tickets
```

Comment: I've tried testing it but getting errors and not knowing sql as well as I would like I'm not sure how to fix it.  I keep changing items to do so but not sure what I'm doing